# Submit mutiple jobs in hazelcast jet

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I have two separate jet pipeline. and I have to execute one by one.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JetInstance instance = Jet.newJetInstance();

        // this job is for stream processing
        JobConfig cfg1 = new JobConfig().setName("CDC-monitor-stream");
        instance.newJob(pipeLine1(), cfg1);

        // this job is for batch processing
        JobConfig cfg2 = new JobConfig().setName("Batch-Processing-monitor");
        instance.newJobIfAbsent(pipeLine2(), cfg2).join();

    }

    public static Pipeline pipeLine1() {
        StreamSource<ChangeRecord> source = PostgresCdcSources.postgres("source")
                .setCustomProperty("plugin.name", "pgoutput").setDatabaseAddress("127.0.0.1").setDatabasePort(5432)
                .setDatabaseUser("postgres").setDatabasePassword("root").setDatabaseName("postgres")
                .setTableWhitelist("public.customers").build();
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create();
        pipeline.readFrom(source).withoutTimestamps().writeTo(CdcSinks.map("customers", r -> r.key().toMap().get("id"),
                r -> r.value().toObject(Customer.class).toString()));
        return pipeline;
    }

    public static Pipeline pipeLine2() {
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create();
        pipeline.readFrom(Sources.map("customers")).filter(e -> e.getKey().equals("0001")).writeTo(Sinks.logger());
        return pipeline;
    }
```

First job is used to have a data sink between db and cache..

second job is used perform the batch processing and using `Sources.map("customers")` as source.(here I'm using batch processing the data extraction is depends on the user input
like `String id="0001", String userName="harry"`  Or Is this possible using stream?)..

Or what is other best approach?

Comment: And what's the question? Multiple jobs can be submitted without any issue.

Comment: @Oliv But both the jobs are executing parallelly.
In the first job I'm storing data in the map named customers.
and second job I'm using  customers map as source but I'm getting empty data..
so how to execute jobs one after another

Comment: Is this your question? Seems like a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69590324/hazelcast-jet-change-data-capture/69613136